Time-orientable Lorentzian manifold
I am reading Lorentzian geometry on my own. We  say a Lorentzian manifold $M$ is a pair $(M,g)$ where $M$ is a  smooth manifold of dimension $(n+1)$ and $g$ is Lorentz metric such that $g$ assigns for each $p\in M$ a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $g_p$ of index $1$.
A nonzero tangent vector $v$ is timelike (resp. lightlike, spacelike) if $g_p(v, v)$ is negative (resp. null, positive). In each tangent space, the
set of lightlike vectors is a cone, called the lightcone, with two connected components.
A Lorentzian manifold M is $\textbf{time-orientable}$ if it is possible to make a continuous choice, in each tangent space, of one of the connected components of the lightcone.
I am confused what does continuous choice mean? Can anyone please help me?

There are many equivalent ways to formalize the word continuous here. My personal choice would be the following. Let $C_p$ denote the chosen connected component of the lightcone in $T_p$. Then continuity means that for any continuous lightlike vector field $v$ the inclusion $v(p) \in C_p$ implies inclusion $v(x) \in C_x$ for all $x$ in some neighborhood of $p$.

Let $TM$ be the tangent bundle of $M$; that is if $T_xM$ is the tangent space at each $x\in M$, then $\textbf{as a set}$:
\begin{align}
TM=\coprod_{x\in M}T_xM
\end{align}
This comes equipped with a natural projection $\pi:TM\rightarrow M$, by taking tangent vector to their base point in $M$, so $v\in T_xM\subset TM$ gets mapped to $x$. We put a topology and smooth structure on $TM$ such that $\pi:TM\rightarrow M$ is smooth, every point $p\in M$ lies in an open subset $U$ such that there eixsts a diffeomorphism $\phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$ which restricts to a linear isomorphism $T_xM\rightarrow \{x\}\times \mathbb R^{n+1}=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ for all $x\in U$, and if $p_U:U\times\mathbb R^{n+1}\rightarrow U$ is the natural projection, then $p_U\circ \phi=\pi$.
Vector fields are then smooth/continuous sections of $\pi$, that is maps $X:M\rightarrow TM$ such that $\pi\circ X=\text{Id}_M$. This implies that for all $p\in M$, $X(p)\in T_pM$, so this is an assignment of a tangent vector in $T_pM$ to each point $p\in M$.
Now, a $\textbf{pointwise orientation}$ of $TM$ is a choice of orientation for each tangent space. A $\textbf{local frame}$ is a set of local vector fields $\{X_1,\dots, X_{n+1}\}$ such that at each point $p$, $\{X_1(p),\dots, X_{n+1}(p)\}$ is a basis for $T_pM$. If the local frame agrees with a pointwise orientation of $TM$, then the frame is an $\textbf{oriented frame}$. A pointwise orientation is then an $\textbf{orienation}$ of $TM$ if all $p\in M$ lie in the domain of a local oriented frame.
Now the following are equivalent:

$TM$  has an orientation
There exists a cover $\{U_i\}$ of $M$, and local trivializations $\psi_i:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that the linear isomrophisms $(\psi_i)_x:T_xM\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ satisfy $(\psi_i)_x\circ (\psi_j)_x^{-1}\in GL^+(n+1)$.

Now, we can generalize this by looking at abstract vector bundles. A vector bundle $E$ is a smooth manifold equipped with a smooth projection $\pi:E\rightarrow M$, such that $E_x:=\pi^{-1}_E(x)$ is a vector space of dimension $k$, every point lies in a trival open set $U$ such that $\phi:\pi^{-1}_E(U)\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{R}^k$, the diffeomorphism restricts to a linear isomorphism on $E_x$, and the projections $\pi_E$, and  $p_U:U\times \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow U$ satistisfies $p_U\circ phi=\pi_E$.
We define an orienation in the same way, and the same two conditions are equivalent. Now, the existence of a metric of index $1$ implies a splitting of the tangent bundle into vector subbundles. That is:
$$TM=S\oplus N$$
where $S$ is a vector bundle over $M$ such that for all $p\in M$ $S_p\subset T_pM$ is a maximally positive definite subspace of $T_pM$, and $N_p\subset T_pM$ is a maximally negative definite subspace $T_pM$.
We say that $M$ is time-orientable if the vector bundle $N$ is orientable. Now the good news here is that $N$ is a rank $1$ vector bundle, so I claim that the condition that $N$ is orientable is equivalent to the existence of a nowhere vanishing time like vector field $X:M\rightarrow TM$ (note that this is essentially what is meant by a continuous choice of a connected component of a light cone).
If such a vector field exists, then I have a basis for $\{X(p)\}$ for each vector space $N_p$. I fix a pointwise orientation by declaring that $X(p)$ is an oriented basis for all $N_p$. Then clearly in $X|_U$ is a local frame for $U\subset N$.
Now suppose $N$ is orientable, and choose a trivializing cover $\{U_i,\phi_i\}$ of $M$ such that $\phi_{ix}\circ \phi_{jx}^{-1}\in SL(1)$.  For each $U_i$, set $X_i(p)=\phi_i^{-1}(p,1)$, where $1\in \mathbb R$. Using a partition of unity $\{\rho_i\}$ subordinate to the cover $\{U_i\}$, we extend each $X_i$ to a global function $\tilde{X}_i=\rho_i\cdot X_i$ which has support contained in $U_i$. Define $X$ to be:
\begin{align}
X=\sum_i\tilde{X}_i
\end{align}
then this sum is finite at each point $p\in M$, and satisfies:
\begin{align}
X(p)=\sum_i\rho_i(p)\phi_{ip}^{-1}(1)
\end{align}
If $p\in U_k$, then we see that:
\begin{align}
\phi_{kp}(X(p))=\sum_i\rho_i(p)(\phi_{kp}\circ \phi_{ip}^{-1})(1)
\end{align}
Each $\rho_i(p)\geq 0$, and not all $\rho_i(p)$ are identically zero. Moverover, since $\phi_{kp}\circ \phi_{ip}^{-1}$ has determinant greater than $0$, and $N_p$ is one dimensional, it follows that this linear isomorphism is multiplication by a real number. We conclude that the sum is nonzero, and always positive, hence $X(p)\neq 0$ for all $p$, and $X$ is a non vanishing section of $N$, and thus a non vanishing time like vector field on $M$.
